# SQL - search for multiple values in multiple large number of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

For searching multiple values within a column we can use the `IN` operator like below

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col IN ('v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e' , 's');
```

However is there way to search for multiple values in multiple columns ? As example - want to select rows where `any` of col1, col2, ..col100 matches something in ('v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e' , 's')

Update:-

While the answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39054997/3206440) by @Gordon will work, the scenario is where the number of columns are many - is there a way to get this done without having to have the repetitive IN statement for each column ?

Comment: Should all cols col1,col2.. match some value in ('v','a'..) or any one match would also do?

Comment: If you does not care about the speed: `select * from your_table where avals(hstore(your_table)) && array['v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e', 's'];` Read about [hstore extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) and about [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is multiple comparisons.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE col1 IN ('v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e' , 's') OR
      col2 IN ('v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e' , 's') OR
      col3 IN ('v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e' , 's') OR
      col4 IN ('v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e' , 's');
```

Your question is unclear on whether `OR` or `AND` would be the right connector.

Note:  Having four columns that contain essentially the same values is suspicious.  You might want to ask another question about your data model itself.

EDIT:

You could use regular expressions:

```
where concat_ws(':', col1, col2, col3, col4) ~ '^[values][:][values][:][values][:][values]$')
```

I consider this inscrutable and hard to maintain, but I'm sure others have different opinions.

Comment: true - I should have added the connector - in this case it would be OR. However I was looking for a case where the number of columns could be many - this gets the job done - but is there another way to handle this without having the IN statement for each col?

Comment: @user3206440 . . . It sounds like the data should be restructured with one row per column value.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function f(col) that checks if it is in ('v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e' , 's') and then use

f(col1) or f(col2) or ...

You have to specify the columns somewhere, so this is getting close to as compact as you can get.

Like the previous response, I would be asking why the col1, col2, etc are not single entries in separate table. There may be a legitimate reason but is is very unusual in my experience - unless you have no control of the DB layout. A separate table is very much the SQL or relational db way of doing this.

Comment: In a similar vein to 2 other comments here, you can use arrays and the any operator:

any(array[col1, col2, ...]) = any(array['v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e' , 's']).

Not sure if I have the syntax right, the syntax is tricky to get right and can't check that from home. This works in Postgres and I think is in the SQL standard, but not sure if other SQL's have it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most beautiful solution, but it does offer some scalability (and less redundancy in code) over the standard solutions:

```
select *
from some_table
where
  to_tsvector (format ('%s %s %s %s %s', col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)) @@
  to_tsquery('v | a | l | u | e | s')
```